# Duvida como fazer insert nesse modelo

Tags: java, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que tem a necessidade de ter uma pessoa física e uma jurídica, gostaria da ajuda para saber como ficaria o `insert` desse modelo [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso eu queira cadastrar uma pessoa física devo fazer dois `insert`?

Answer (score 2):

Sim. Primeiro você insere na tabela pai (tbPessoa) e depois na tabela filha (tbPessoaFisica ou tbPessoaJuridica).

```
INSERT INTO tbPessoa ('nmPessoa', 'dsEmail')
VALUES ('João', 'joao@gmail.com');

INSERT INTO tbPessoaFisica ('cdCpf', 'idPessoa')
VALUES ('78945698745', 'pk do insert de cima');
```

Comment: No caso do metodo que vai fazer o insert vai ter duas String sql =

Comment: e vai ter dois pst.execute();? ou um só?

Comment: Como você utiliza JDBC, vai ter dois Sqls. Da uma olhada nesse link: https://javahunter.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/use-of-prepared-statement-and-getting-foriegn-key-from-master-table/

Comment: Está bem obrigado

Comment: O Insert deu tudo certo, mas agora eu posso utilizar essa logica para fazer o update no meu cliente certo?

Comment: Exato. Utilize a mesma lógica. :)

Comment: Tudo certo, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda.